# verifier failure for a xdp code computing icmp checksum?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bpf, xdp-bpf

I am using xdp(use XDP_TX action) to construct an icmp resv packets.

linux: centos8

kernel 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64

llvm: 7.0.1

clang: clang version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)

Here is my code:

```
SEC("xdp_icmp")
int _xdp_icmp(struct xdp_md *xdp)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)xdp->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)xdp->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct icmphdr *icmph;
    __u16 h_proto;
    __be32 raddr;

    ....
    icmph = data + sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*iph);
    if (icmph + 1 > data_end)
        return  XDP_DROP;

    if (icmph -> type != ICMP_ECHO)
    {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    if (handle_ipv4(xdp) != XDP_TX)
    {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    raddr = iph->saddr;
    swap_src_dst_mac(data);
    iph->saddr = iph->daddr;
    iph->daddr = raddr;
    icmph->type = ICMP_ECHOREPLY;
    icmph->checksum = 0;
    __u32 sum = 0;
    sum = bpf_csum_diff(0, 0, icmph, ICMP_ECHO_LEN, 0);
    icmph->checksum = csum_fold_helper(sum);
    return XDP_TX;
}
```

But the compilation result told me "verifier failure":

error:

```
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Permission denied
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf:
...
48: (b7) r5 = 0
49: (85) call bpf_csum_diff#28
invalid access to packet, off=34 size=64, R3(id=0,off=34,r=42)
R3 offset is outside of the packet
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when calling:

```c
// s64 bpf_csum_diff(__be32 *from, u32 from_size, __be32 *to, u32 to_size, __wsum seed)
sum = bpf_csum_diff(0, 0, icmph, ICMP_ECHO_LEN, 0);
```

The `to_size` passed as third argument should be a number of bytes. Assuming that you copied `ICMP_ECHO_LEN` from kernel selftests, I suspect its value is 64, thus asking the kernel to compute a checksum on a 64-bytes long buffer. But you never checked that your packet was that long (you have `if (icmph + 1 > data_end)`, which looks correct to me).

I suspect you should try instead to pass the length of your header as the third argument, something like this (not tested):

```c
um = bpf_csum_diff(0, 0, icmph, sizeof(struct icmphdr), 0);
```

`struct icmphdr` is defined in `include/uapi/linux/icmp.h` and seems to have a length of 8 bytes, although you do not need to know this and should be fine as long as you pass the correct length for your header.